# Data recovery /repair of a HDD drive

Tags: hard-drive

In continuation of this question I asked earlier and replies I got there:

https://superuser.com/q/249377/4143

Thanks for the pointers to this problem given by many.

Connected the 'faulty' hard disk drive(Western Digital 500 TB)  to another working Dell Vostro PC, and it did not work there either. So in all probability the HDD is bad. Now my next quest, unless I have hit a dead end as to this faulty HDD,is try to recover some data from it.

I understand in a HDD failure one can have either of the following going bad causing the HDD not to be recognized by Bios. -- HDD firmware going bad -- HDD controller becoming faulty -- HDD physical magnetic material going bad. -- Anything else??

Now if I want to try and give a shot at recovering this disk and data in it, what are my chances and if at all what steps should I take. Give it to a professional hard disk recovery engineers etc.

If say MBR of this is gone bad, Can it be connected and recognized as some secondary /slave disk to other desktop system?

Is there any thing such as 'repairing' a hard disk given its so commoditized (£19.20 is what Dell charged me for a new one.)?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [freeze method](http://geeksaresexy.blogspot.com/2006/01/freeze-your-hard-drive-to-recover-data.html) if you are experiencing the "clicking" hard drive symptom.  Note that the guide says to chill for an hour... I recommend several.  If the trick works you have a few minutes to recover data before the drive heats up so act on sub-folders and act quickly.  You can re-freeze the drive and try again once it stops responding.